# How to access API Gateway request Model in Lambda function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda function mapped to API Gateway, where I have Models defined for the request input and response output.

But how to I access that model in the Lambda function (node) code?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not natively supported in Lambda/API Gateway. You could certainly make a request to the API Gateway service to get the model information or simply hard code this information in the Lambda function.

Comment: Hm, so if I'm using a generated sdk to pass some data up to the api gateway (post) method, how are you suggesting I get it in the lambda? Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, based on your answer I guess I misinterpreted your question. I thought you wanted to know how to get the model definition, not the actual modeled values. If you wanted the definition, you would need to make a call to GetModel via the AWS SDK (not the generated SDK).

Answer (score 0):

OK turns out this is very easy! The model defined in API gateway is available right as the event parameter to the lambda handler method. This will write it to a log:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, '  '));
```

And an individual field on that object can be accessed like:

```
console.log("Model property value: " + event.foo);
```